# Button combination

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get input from the user in a `type="number"` text box.
the limitation is a number between 1994-1998.
I currently have two buttons. One "submit" button and a second ("button") button that goes to the next screen.
I want to make the 2 buttons one.
Which means that as soon as I click the "Move to Next page" button, the input is also checked.
And you can move to the next screen only with proper input.
 would much rather do it only with HTML and less with JavaScript if possible.
If there is no option then it is also possible with JavaScript.

```js
function check () {
  console.log('Checked!');
}
```

```html
<div>
  between 1994 and 1998: <input id="section5input" type="number" name="quantity" min="1994" max="1998">
  <input type="submit">
  <a href="#section6" type="button" class="btn">Calculate the answers!</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="box" id="section6">
  <h1>fin!</h1>
  <div class="question-text">
    <input style="padding: 20px;" type="button" class="btn" onclick="check();">check!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Qiniso Please do not make edits that change the names of languages to code formatting. They are not code and do not need the format change.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to go to next page only if input is correct then check this out. I have created a `form` and placed your html inside it. Now the submit button will only work if `check` function return `true`.

```js
function check(){
    //return true, if correct
    //return false, if incorrect
   return true;
 }
```

```html
<form action='yourURLforNextPage' method="POST">
  Between 1994 and 1998: 
  <input id="section5input" type="number" name="quantity" min="1994" max="1998">
  <input type="submit" onclick="return check();">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check(){
let val = document.getElementById("section5input");
   if((val.value!= "" && null) && (val.value> 1994 && val.value<1998) ){
      //code to render to next screen
   }
 }
```

Comment: While your code may answer the question, you should add a brief explanation of what you have done and why